# Shared layout has different values in different languages

Tags: presentation, sitecore-client

This is the behaviour in sitecore8.2

As shared Layout is a shared field i thought the value of shared layout will be same for all item languages and versions. 
But i found its not if we set different final layout in the __standardValues.

All i have changed in Danish language is moving "Sample Rendering" to the middle.

I feel its better to demonstrate with a video. 
Video Link: http://www.screencast.com/t/Iye0s1eN

Is this the expected behaviour, if yes how can shared field can have different values?

**Update:**

Raw values of Renderings field on both English and Danish are same. Its just happening only on the UI looks like.

Comment: That looks like a bug to me. Have you compared the raw values in the Renderings field on the home page? I wonder if the Renderings field is overwritten in the UI if you change the order of the renderings in the final renderings field. It shouldn't but it looks like that is what is happening.

Comment: Yes, raw values of Renderings field on both English and Danish are same. Its just happening only on the UI looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference - below is the response from sitecore support.

> I have created an Info Request to our Product team regarding this behavior.
>   The Product team has confirmed that the current behavior in Sitecore is by design according to this article:https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/versioned_layouts/versioned_layouts
>
> Let me explain why this behavior is by design.
>   When you enable ‘Raw value’ you can see that __Renderings field is the same in different languages, as this field is really shared.
>   But when you open Presentation>Details>Shared Layout you can see that ‘Shared Layout’ is different in different languages. This happens because ‘Shared Layout’ is a dynamic field and created by the following scheme: Standard Values Shared + Standard Values Final.
>
> Also, you can look at the following Release Notes and the article, which describes the order of applying the versioned layouts.
>   https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/8%200/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%208%200/Release%20Notes.
>   https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/versioned_layouts/versioned_layouts
>
> As I understand directly the name ‘Shared Layout’ is confusing you. According to this, I have registered the wish that renames ‘Shared Layout’ to ‘Default Layout’.
>
> To track the future status of this wish, please use the reference number 141479. More information about public reference numbers can be found here:
>   https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/853187

So this means we can actually have different shared layout for different languages if we set final layout in standard values.

Answer (score 1):

You should raise this as a bug with Sitecore. Since the raw values are correct the bug must be in the Sitecore pipeline that resolves the renderings and the order of those renderings. But it would be interesting to see if it is only happening in the Sitecore UI or if it also affects the actual order of the renderings when you publish the page. I would expect the latter and that they use the same pipeline to resolve the renderings. In any case it should be sent to Sitecore Support.

Comment: Yes, i already did. I wil update here when i get back an update from support